# Rejecting SMS in BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, sms, block

Android allows to listen on incoming SMS. Can the message be rejected and non delivery report sent?

After setting up the appropriate permissions and listeners, incoming SMS can be read.

```
public class MySmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Can read incoming SMS here
    }
}
```

While app can choose not to save the SMS, I would like the sender to not receive the delivery status success message. Either no delivery status to be sent back or a failure. Can that be done?

Comment: When an SMS reaches the Android app level it is already received and processed by the RIL, so for rejecting it, it is a little bit too late.

Comment: Thanks, I feared that might be the case. I run into https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Telephony.Sms.Intents and hoped I could send `RESULT_SMS_OUT_OF_MEMORY` back to Android. Now the sender would receive the delivery status success message even when `BroadcastReceiver` fails to save the message and the recipient never sees it.